# Strange behaviour of Firefox debugger when testing value for not null

Tags: javascript

Today I was debugging a certain part of our JavaScript web application.

I am using the native Firefox debugger (Firefox version 38.0.8).

In the screenshot you see that the debugger is currently at line 386. 
But I do not understand this (same behaviour also in Firebug). JavaScript can
only be at line 386, when "value" is not null, but in this case "value" is null.

How can this be?  What did I miss?

[image]

You see it clearer in Firebug. In Firebug null is italic. I thought this must be an indication for not being a string.

[image]

How can I distinguish between null and "null" in Firebug or Firefox native debugger?

I changed the value for value in Firebug to a "null" string, now it is in double quotes.

[image]

Now I tried it with the Google Chrome debugger. This one is doing it right. 
The current line - after line 385 - is 390, it did not go to line 386.

[image]

Thank you, Barmar, for your suggestion to insert an alert.
It went into the if clause, but jumped over "alert" into line 387.
It did not execute the alert.
So is there a problem with the line synchronisation?
[image]

Comment: Could it possibly be the text value of `"null"` rather than an actual `Null` value?

Comment: `value` is a proper `null`, otherwise it would show up as `"null"` in the window scope list (on the right).

Comment: If you put an `alert` or `console.log` call in that `if` block, does it fire?

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint then edit your script and reload? I think this may have caused it to get out of sync between the breakpoints and the script lines.